# Lazy loading for angular services

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I have created module in Angular 4. Also i created service using @Injectable, added to module. Now my requirement is , service should not load during module loading. once i perform action or event like click, then service should load. So please help me how to implement this requirement.

thanks,
Narsi p

Answer (score 1):

You have to use injector explicitly. The injector is the one which instantiate the service.

Suppose square is the service,

```
class Square { name = 'square'; }
```

Call the service in component using below code.

```
const injector = Injector.create({providers: [{provide: Square, deps: []}]}); 
const shape: Square = injector.get(Square);
expect(shape.name).toEqual('square');
expect(shape instanceof Square).toBe(true);
```

Comment: create method doesn't existed in Injector class. Injector.create throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular 6 then there is a feature provided by angular itself to lazy load services by using it's new syntax.

```
@Injectable({
   providdedIn : 'root'
})
```

Using this way Service can be loaded lazy by angular behind the scene, which will remove redundant code and lead to better performance and speed.